# Android client app not getting server response despite server successfully sending socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to request information through a socket on an Android client and then receive it back from the server through another socket but I am not receiving the information sent from server on the client side.

This is the code for my client on Android:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        binding = FragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        runThreads = true;
        new ResponseListener().start();
        queryAllOrders();

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    private void queryAllOrders()
    {
        try
        {
            if (socket != null)
            {
                DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                output.writeUTF("§§Q0");
                output.flush();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Orders queried successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error querying orders", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error querying orders", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private static class ResponseListener extends Thread
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());;
                while (runThreads)
                {
                    String mes = input.readUTF();
                    if (mes.startsWith("§§R0"))
                    {
                        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(MainApplication.getAppContext()).execute(() ->
                                Toast.makeText(MainApplication.getAppContext(), "Response received successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
                        System.out.println("Response received successfully | Message: " + mes);
                    }
                    if (runThreads)
                        input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                }
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView()
    {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
        runThreads = false;
    }
}
```

And this is the thread on my server which detects an input:

```
    private static class ClientInput extends Thread
    {
        private final int clientId;
        private final Socket socket;

        DataInputStream input;
        DataOutputStream output;

        public ClientInput(int clientId, Socket socket) throws IOException
        {
            this.clientId = clientId;
            this.socket = socket;

            input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                while (runThreads)
                {
                    String mes = input.readUTF();

                    if (mes.startsWith("§§Q"))
                    {
                        if (mes.charAt(3) == '0')
                        {
                            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder("§§R0%");
                            for (Order order : orders)
                            {
                                response.append(order.toString());
                                response.append("%");
                            }
                            response.deleteCharAt(response.length() - 1);
                            serverWrite("\nSent all orders to client with ID: " + clientId + " | Host : " +  socket.getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName());
                            serverWrite("Orders: " + response);
                            output.writeUTF(response.toString());
                            output.flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                if (e.getMessage() == null)
                    serverWrite("\nConnection with a client lost");
                else
                {
                    if (e.getMessage().equals("Connection reset"))
                        serverWrite("\nConnection with a client lost");
                    else
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I open the fragment on the client, it sends the request to the server and on the server-side, I see that a response is sent back to the client. However, I don't receive that response on the client and the code stays on the `input.readUTF()`.

Comment: `if (runThreads)
                        input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());` Remove that statement. You already opened it just before the while loop.

Comment: You cannot use a Toast() there where you read or write to sockets.

Comment: `then receive it back from the server through another socket ` ? What do you mean with 'another socket'? Where do you have it?

Comment: @blackapps I'm going to be honest, I don't even know why the `if (runThreads)` line was there, but  I removed it and it didn't fix it. Regarding the Toast(), removing it also didn't fix the issue. I've realised that the first time that the fragment is loaded, it works perfectly, but the issue arises for every other time which the fragment is opened apart from the first time